# Number of Active Database Connections Performance Counters?

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012-r2, database, oracle, performance-counters

We are using [OleDbConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection(v=vs.110).aspx) class to connect Oracle and SqlServer. At some places we are also using SqlClient and Oracle.DataAccess.OracleConnection. I need to know how many active connections our servers have using Performance counter.

Our DBA is blaming us that we are not closing connections. But we are sure that we are closing connection(we are putting connection in C# using).

Comment: for sql server you can look at  perf_counter["\SQLServer:General Statistics\User Connections"] . take care if you use named instance you have to check with perf monitor.

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle you can use V$SESSION view 
 https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2088.htm#REFRN30223

Something like this:

```
select LOGON_TIME, OSUSER, PROCESS, PROGRAM, MACHINE\
from V$SESSION \
where MACHINE = 'YOUR CLIENT HOSTNAME' and STATUS != 'KILLED';
```

In case connections are initiated from different clients but from the same Application name - you can filter based on PROGRAM

```
WHERE regexp_like(PROGRAM,'Your Program Name','i');
```

Or you can do it based on netstat output.
Like this

```
netstat -anp | grep ":1521" | grep 'ESTABLISHED' | grep 'Your CLIENT IP' | wc -l
```

Similar technic based on netstat can be applied on SQL Server

```
netstat -ano | find /I ":1433" | find /I "ESTABLISHED" | find /I "Your client IP" /c
```